# JQuery won't load from a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is make a stock .html file with the nav, footer, basically anything I'd use on multiple pages and want to change easily. This is a small 20ish page site I'm working on and I really don't want to rely on php or something.

I've looked at other responses on here and followed them precisely but they don't seem to help me at all, although it's probably something I'm overlooking.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href='files/stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>

<!--Navigation-->
<div id='navigation'></div>
<script>$("#navigation").load("templete.html #nav");</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance! -Shy♥

Comment: Do you really mean for it to be spelled `"templete.html"`.

Comment: I misspelled it when I was saving the document, so I just typed it that way again here. Was more focused on getting this to function first before fixing my document name typos. :P

Comment: What is in `"templete.html"` and is it in the same web-server directory as the file you're working on?   Have you looked in the browser error console for errors?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/sTFafv3L

Comment: No, it's not working.

Comment: Can you paste here any console errors you might have?

Comment: It doesn't say I have any errors.

Comment: Is your template on a web server or in the local file system?  Some browsers will not let you load files with ajax from the local file system.

Comment: Some browsers do not allow using Ajax for local files. Use a web server.

Comment: It's just a local file, the thing is that when I take out the #nav and just leave it as templete.html it'll load the entire document. The problem is the ID but I've triple checked it and everything should be fine..

Comment: Is it just me or should templete.html #nav be templete.html#nav

Comment: I've also tried that Mathijs and it didn't work.

Comment: @ColdHands You should check the browser's network tab. It shows what exactly is going on. Please do no develop with closed eyes.

Comment: The method is set to OPTIONS instead of GET.

Answer (score 0):

Is it cust a typo templete.html (third line from below). Otherwis, take a look at the jQuery docs and the restrictions of the functions (http://api.jquery.com/load/).